# Can't generate alpha-numero-symbolic string at a fixed size

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that suggests a *strong password* for a user if the user does not have a password idea of his/her own.  The idea is that the user selects the size of the password (4 radio buttons), password characteristics (4 checkboxes) & hits generate.  Based on this selection, I am *trying* to generate a random string:

```
private String generatedPassword(){
    int length = 0;
    StringBuilder generatedString = new StringBuilder();
    Random rand = new Random();

    if(radio4.isSelected()){length = 4;}
    else if(radio8.isSelected()){length = 8;}
    else if(radio12.isSelected()){length = 12;}
    else if(radio16.isSelected()){length = 16;}

    if(passwordABCD.isSelected()){totalCharacters += capitalLetters;}
    if(passwordabcd.isSelected()){totalCharacters += lowercaseLetters;}
    if(password0123.isSelected()){totalCharacters += numbers;}
    if(passwordSymbols.isSelected()){totalCharacters += characters;}

    char[] text = new char[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){text[i] = totalCharacters.charAt(rand.nextInt(length));}

    for (char c : text) { generatedString.append(c); }

    return generatedString.toString();
}
```

and setting the EditText of this string when the user clicks "Generate"

```
GenerateDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

    ...

    generatePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            passwordEditText.setText(generatedPassword());
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

But unfortunately, nothing is visible in the `passwordEditText` Edit Text field.

Comment: It's not the cause of your issue but you should not use `rand.nextInt(length)`. You should use `rand.nextInt(totalCharacters.length())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input elements might not deliver what one think, hence ensure that the control parameters `length` and `totalCharacter` are okay. `isChecked` was already mentioned by **@AGDownie**.

```
private static final String numbers = "0918273645";
...
```

and

```
String totalCharacters = "";
if (passwordABCD.isSelected()) {totalCharacters += capitalLetters;}
if (passwordabcd.isSelected()) {totalCharacters += lowercaseLetters;}
if (password0123.isSelected()) {totalCharacters += numbers;}
if (passwordSymbols.isSelected()) {totalCharacters += characters;}
if (totalCharacters.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least one kind of symbols required.");
}
if (length == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty password not allowed.");
}

char[] text = new char[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text[i] = totalCharacters.charAt(rand.nextInt(totalCharacters.length()));
}
return new String(text);
```

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is that if `passwordABCD` is unchecked afterwards, the value has already been concatenated into `totalCharacters` and hence no way to extract them afterwards

Comment: You saw above that I moved totalCharacters just before the if's, at every function call it is filled anew.

Comment: Ah okay.  You're right.  But when I hit the `generate` button without selecting a radio button or a check box, the app crashes with `SearchServiceClient: Starting with NO_SESSION handoverId is deprecated. Just don't. You will break.`

Comment: Instead of my throws you need some error handling. Maybe an error message, _before_ calling the function, or enabling the button only when at least one check box is selected, and a length was selected too.

Comment: You're right.  Thank you for your answer.  I've accepted it and gave you an upvote.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: @oo92 in general upvotes are for questions that might interest others as well. This means a _downvote_ is not necessarily a form of criticism.  Here an upvote is a border case; with a bit of debugging or those fail-fast tests from my code, you would have found the errors. But for the security enhancing code +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `isChecked()` method on your buttons rather than `isSelected()`.

Also you might want to simplify your code by removing the unnecessary `char[]` array and instead do somthing like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   generatedString.append(totalCharacters.charAt(rand.nextInt(totalCharacters.length()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've implemented your for-loop in my code.  I've upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?